# How to disable a group of checkboxes if no checkbox in the other group is selected

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox

I guess it's pretty simple, but unfortunately I don't know JavaScript at all and wasn't able to find an already existing solution.

```
<input type='checkbox' class='group1' name='1'> Name1<br>    
<input type='checkbox' class='group1' name='2'> Name2<br>     
<input type='checkbox' class='group1' name='3'> Name3<br><br>   
<input type='checkbox' class='group2' name='4'> Name4<br>    
<input type='checkbox' class='group2' name='5'> Name5<br>
```

So, if neither `Name1`, `Name2`, nor `Name3` is selected, `Name4` and `Name5` should be disabled.

Thanks in advance, guys!

As my page already has jQuery included into its < head > section, I decided to use the variant which requires this library.
So, I tried the code **Wing Leong** offered and it was a success. However, it has the two following drawbacks:

1. I forgot to mention that disabled checkboxes should be explicitly set unchecked. In the current implementation, when I select one of the checkboxes in the second group (for instance, `Name4`) and then uncheck all the checkboxes in the first one, `Name4` becomes disabled but still checked. This is completely wrong, because a server processing the form will accept `Name4` as the selected option. If it is not true, a user do may get confused.
2. On this page, I have another jQuery script, which automatically selects all the checkboxes of the first group when a user selects a checkbox called 'Check all'. Here it is:

   ```
   <input type='checkbox' id='maincb'> Check all
   ```

And JavaScript for this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready( function() {       
     $("#maincb").click( function() {    
if($('#maincb').attr('checked')) {    
    $('.group1:enabled').attr('checked', true);    
} else {    
    $('.group1:enabled').attr('checked', false);    
}    
});    
    });    
</script>
```

The problem is, these two scripts don't do well with each other. Even after my assigning the class `group1` to the checkbox 'Check all', it doesn't affect the checkboxes of the second group anyhow.

Comment: You'll have to define disabled... Invisible? Unclickable? Unsendable? All?

Comment: @zozo: there's a disabled attribute `<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />`

Comment: Yeah... but it used to have some problems a while ago. Anyway... you got 999 answers while I was afk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want work like this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/steelywing/MtDLB/1/

```
$('#check_group1').click(function () {
    $('.group1:enabled').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    updateButton();
});

function updateButton() {
    if ($('.group1:checked').length == 0) {
        $('.group2')
            .prop('disabled', true)
            .prop("checked", false);
    } else {
        $('.group2').prop('disabled', false);
    }
}

$('.group1').change(function () {
    updateButton();
});

updateButton();
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. I updated my post to add some important details about your script.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<input type='checkbox' class='group1' name='1'> Name1<br>    
<input type='checkbox' class='group1' name='2'> Name2<br>     
<input type='checkbox' class='group1' name='3'> Name3<br><br>   
<input type='checkbox' class='group2' name='4'> Name4<br>    
<input type='checkbox' class='group2' name='5'> Name5<br>
```

**JavaScript (pure, no jQuery)**

```
function checkFields() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    if (inputs.length == 5) {
        if (inputs[0].checked == true || inputs[1].checked == true || inputs[2].checked == true) {
            inputs[3].disabled = false;
            inputs[4].disabled = false;
        }
        else {
            inputs[3].disabled = true;
            inputs[4].disabled = true;
        }
    }
}

// On-load
checkFields();

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        checkFields();
    });
}
```

Might put the initial `checkFields();` into `<body onload="">`. Also keep in mind you want to target the `document.getElementsByTagName('input');` on a parent wrapper with an ID, to not accidentally match other input-fields on the page.

**HTML**

```
<form id="wrappingForm">
    <input type='checkbox' class='group1' name='1'> Name1<br>    
    <input type='checkbox' class='group1' name='2'> Name2<br>     
    <input type='checkbox' class='group1' name='3'> Name3<br><br>   
    <input type='checkbox' class='group2' name='4'> Name4<br>    
    <input type='checkbox' class='group2' name='5'> Name5<br>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrappingForm');
var inputs = wrapper.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

Answer (score 0):

Is Jquery an option? If so it's very simple...

```
    $('input').click(function() {

        if ($('.group1').is(':checked')) {
             $('.group2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');  
        } else {
            $('.group2').removeAttr('disabled');
        }

    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EkxgH/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type=text/javascript>
function clk(){
if (op1.checked == 1 && op2.checked == 1 && op3.checked == 1){
          op4.checked=1 ;
          op5.checked=1 ;
}
}
</script>


<input type='checkbox' class='group1' onclick="clk()" name='op1'> Name1<br>    
<input type='checkbox' class='group1' onclick="clk()" name='op2'> Name2<br>     
<input type='checkbox' class='group1' onclick="clk()" name='op3'> Name3<br> 
<input type='checkbox' class='group2' name='op4'> Name4<br>    
<input type='checkbox' class='group2' name='op5'> Name5<br>
```